PostgreSQL query with index is taking 10x longer than without
I tried to limit the amount of rows returned by adding
...
   where 
        received_at >= current_date - interval '2 years'
...


to my query.
This caused the optimiser to start using an index on received_at (it should I hoped for it) however it also lengthened the duration of the query 10-fold.... (which I definitely did not expect).
Here are the explain plans:

Explain plan query without filter
Explain plan query with filter - 10x longer....

The query with filter that uses the Index is starting to do a lot of IO.
What is causing this?
What is the best next action?
Using PostgreSQL 15.

Could you share the query and the DDL for the tables and indexes as well? One thing that caught my eye, is the index dim_date_hist_idx_calender_date_current_flag, where the "date" column is missing. The index is used, and then 95% of the results are dropped. Not your biggest problem, but it does have an impact in planning the query.

Here are table & index detail: https://explain.depesz.com/s/6DmM#html

When using the index scan, it reads the index in logical order but then needs to jump all over the table fetching the rows.  This means it will need to visit the table in random order (assuming the ordering of rows in the physical table layout is not correlated with the indexed column), not sequential order, and that it will need to visit the same table blocks repeatedly. Both of these things can slow it down.
The planner should know both of these things and so decide not do use the index scan in this case, preferring either the seq scan or the bitmap scan.  But you've probably gone out of your way to mislead the planner about the efficiency of random reads vs sequential reads, by, for example, lowering random_page_cost to be equal to seq_page_cost.

Good pointer. Based on having SSDs we lowered the random_page_cost to 1.1 , with a sequential_page cost of 1. However, read the PostgreSQLmanual again and saw the note on the relation with RAM available as opposed to database size. Tried other values for random_page_cost. The default (4) did not work either (sic!). A random_page_cost=8 did work. I'm a bit hesistant making it 8 for the complete database

Have you done any benchmarking of your SSD?  They are not all created equal and some are surprisingly bad at random read workload.  Based on the plans I could see, I'm surprised increasing random_page_cost to 4 didn't work.  What was the plan with the increased setting (the same shape as the existing one I suppose, but what are the actual cost estimates?)
